# Parsing Json in php to respond to HTTP GET request

Tags: php, json, http, parsing, http-get

I want to create a php script that allows my Android client app to ask for cities that match with a string through HTTP get method.

I am not very familiar with php but I ended up with this script:

```
<?php

function starts_with($string, $query) {
    return substr($string, 0, strlen($query)) === $query // TODO: ignore case
}

$constraint = $_GET['const']

$string = file_get_contents("/home/cities.json"); 
$cities = json_decode($string, true); // Json array filled with Json objects, each one representing a city

$matches = array();

foreach ($cities as $city) { 
    if (startsWith($city->name, $constraint)) {
        $matches[] = $city
    }

} 

echo json_encode($matches);

?>
```

The fact is that my json file is a huge file (~20Mb) and contains almost 220k "lines".
I previously implemented this on the client side in Java using Jackson parser that is exactly adapted to this kind of huge json file as long as it process the file through nodes and do not parse the file entirely in one time.
So I feel like my script is not adapted to the 20mb file that it will load. Is there any way of doing this in a better way ?
Thanks

Comment: You actually don't need a 20mb json file, why don't you store the **data** intoo a **data base**?

Comment: Yes i think you need to save these records in database first and then just query with certain limit.

Comment: The fact is that the file containing cities is not created by myself and comes from a weather API provider, so this is the only format available. I imagine I'll have to write a script to parse this file and insert each city in a dB, but I am not very familiar with php so if I can, I would prefer to avoid getting into setting a db. There is no "efficient parser"  in php ?